# How to get selector as function when using $ in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Normally, I use `$` in the project then getting the result as a function but when I use `$` in Angular project i get result as HTML content like that. So, how can i get result as function like usual when using `$` in Angular ?

$ in Normal Project ( just HTML Javascript ) Result

```
$('.page')
   result -> n.fn.init(2) [div.page, div.page, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: ".page"]
```

$ in Angular Project

```
$('.page')
result -> <div class="page" data-page-number="1" style="width: 1143px; height: 1476px;"><div class="loadingIcon"></div></div>
```

Comment: Usually the $ is a short cut for JQuery.  Are you trying to use JQuery and Angular in the same project?  I strongly recommend against mixing the two.  Perhaps if you explain what you're trying to accomplish we can guide you better.

Comment: @JeffryHouser the reason i do that cause I want to get the offset().top (position) of element but when using $ in angular just return dom element and I can't use method offset().top like normal project ?

Comment: If you explain what you are trying to do, perhaps we can guide you; but I strongly recommend against mixing Angular and JQuery.

Comment: @JeffryHouser thank you guy, I'd solved my problem.